# JSON field into CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I have a Postgres JSON field - after calling JSON.parse on it, I get an array of hashes - here's a sample:

```
[{"fips": "12345, "city": "Atlanta", "state": "IL", "zip": "61723"}, {"fips": "24567", "city": "Lincoln", "state": "IL", "zip": "62656"}]
```

I have a method that extracts city, state & zip. I have another method that inserts it into a CSV. Here's my extraction method:

```
def address(in_arr)
  in_arr.map do |h|
    h.select { |k, v| "#{k}: #{v}\n" unless k.eql?('fips') }
  end
end
```

I need the cells in my CSV file to look like:

```
city: Atlanta
state: IL
zip: 61723
```

etc...

but I'm getting:

```
[{"city"=>"Atlanta"}, {"state"=>"IL"}, {"zip"=>"61723"}]
```

I've tried *map* instead of *select*, I've tried inserting *puts* within the inner *select*, etc., but it never displays correctly. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input.map { |hash| hash.to_a[1..-1].map { |e| e.join(': ') } }
#⇒ [["city: Atlanta", "state: IL", "zip: 61723"],
#   ["city: Lincoln", "state: IL", "zip: 62656"]]
```

---

Or

```
input.map do |hash|
  hash.reject { |k, _| k == :fips }.map(&:zip).map { |e| e.join(': ') }
end
```

---

Or

```
keys = %i|city state zip|
input.map do |hash|
  keys.zip(hash.values_at(*keys)).map { |e| e.join(': ') }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Your data is in following format,

```
 data = [{"city"=>"Atlanta"}, {"state"=>"IL"}, {"zip"=>"61723"}]
```

Create csv to write in file in following format,

```
CSV.generate(headers: false) { |csv| hash.map(&:to_a).each { |row| csv << row } }

# => "\"[\"\"city\"\", \"\"Atlanta\"\"]\"\n\"[\"\"state\"\", \"\"IL\"\"]\"\n\"[\"\"zip\"\", \"\"61723\"\"]\"\n"
```

[CSV.generate](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-generate) is proper way to convert your data in `csv` format.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to solve your problem would be to just return the values of your current hash assuming that your getting back a correct hash.  You can use the hash values method as defined in the [ruby API](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-values).

I was able to achieve the expected results by doing the following,

```
ex_hash = [
          {'fips': '12345', 'city': 'Atlanta', 'state': 'IL', 'zip': '61723'}, 
          {'fips': '24567', 'city': 'Lincoln', 'state': 'IL', 'zip': '62656'}
        ]

keys_to_extract = [:city, :state, :zip]

address_values = []
ex_hash.each do |h| # iterate over the hash
  address_values << h.select { |k,_| keys_to_extract.include? k }.values # extract values 
end

puts address_values.inspect # [["Atlanta", "IL", "61723"], ["Lincoln", "IL", "62656"]]
```

Or additionally as mentioned in the comments by Aleksei Matiushkin.

```
address_values = ex_hash.map { |h| h.select { |k,_| keys_to_extract.include? k }.value }
```

Comment: You are abusing `map` for iterating, it makes zero sense. Iteration in Ruby is to be done with `each`. Use `address_values = ex_hash.map { |h| h.select { |k,_| keys_to_extract.include? k }.value }` instead.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin good point.  We don't need the extra overhead returning a new array.  I'll modify above to each, then also add your suggestion in the edited comment.